# Is there any way to change font in HTML without CSS

Tags: html, fonts

I am trying to make a simple HTML website without CSS, and I am wondering how to change the font to a font I downloaded from another website (It is a ttf file).
If it is impossible without CSS, how would I do it with CSS?

Comment: Question: why not CSS? It provides a lot of benefits (think consistency, reusability, flexibility) without many disadvantages. - Avoiding it seems like the wrong direction

Comment: Why not use CSS? Arbitrary challenge?

Comment: You HAVE to use css. You do not need an additional css file you can directly write it in your html code but have a look at http://www.w3schools.com how you implement it.

Answer (score 3):

you will need both, HTML is the foundation and CSS is the paint. You can build a website with just HTML but it wouldnt be very pretty. you can do the fonts with CSS like below.. font-family is the name of the font so you can declare where ever you want it to apply on the webpage.. and src is the link to your font.

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(sansation_light.woff);
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp - this will show you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the css (with `theFontName` being your font name, and `fontURL` being the relative path to your font on the server:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: theFontName
    src: url(fontURL.ttf);
}
```

Comment: OP said "without css"